# Reading large excel tables (guessing size)

Tags: python, excel, vba, com, pywin32

I'm using pywin32 to read and write to excel. Now the only method I know is accessing Range.Value however, I usually don't know the size of the full excel table in advance.
So at the moment I read line by line until I find a completely empty line. This can be quite slow.

Of course I will try tricks like reading blocks of data - then I'd have to find an optimal block size.

Do you know another method (maybe some internal excel function) or other approaches which are faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VBA, we often use the `End` statement like this:

```
Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

That may help you find the last used cell of a column (yet, I don't know how to extend this method to `pywin`)

Comment: Thanks. This might work. Btw, in pywin it's all the same - probably mapped somehow :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [xlrd](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) to open a workbook and read the size of particular worksheet. It's quite fast.

Hints: `book = xlrd.open_workbook("myfile.xls")` then you get Sheet object by `sheet = book.sheet_by_index(sheetx)` or `sheet = book.sheet_by_name(sheet_name)` and you have `sheet.nrows` property with number of rows in given sheet.

Here is the [API](http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html) documentation.

Answer (score 2):

How about getting the whole range with the [Worksheet.UsedRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.usedrange%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) property ?

Comment: Interesting. Is it like the maximum filled row? It probably works if I have only one table on the worksheet :)

Comment: @Gerenuk: it's useful when you want to select everything in the worksheet. If you have many tables the range will include all of them.